# Using Xcode8 with a swift 2.3 project that uses cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift3

I have a project with a light amount of code written in what I assume is swift 2.3   It contains and app extension also written in swift 2.3 and uses 2 Cocoapods: `SwiftyJSON` and `MMWormhole`.  After downloading Xcode 8.3 beta, the migrator ran and I am left with almost 100 compiler errors in the one main swift file contained in `SwiftyJSON`.

Basically I want to know if there is a way I can work in Xcode8 given these details.  I am happy to update my own code to swift3 however I do not control the cocoapods (MMWormHole is in objective-C so I assume that Xcode converts that to whichever version of Swift it needs as it emits no compiler errors).  Can I tell Xcode to use swift 2.3 globally?

Answer (score 6):

You have to set `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `YES` to make use `SWIFT 2.3` code in `Xcode 8`. Then add this into your `Podfile` to make all of your pod targets confirm the same.

```
post_install do |installer| 
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
      configuration.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = "2.3" 
    end 
  end 
end
```

I hope, it will help.

Comment: This was really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Many open source Swift projects have branches for Swift 3 or Swift 2.3 (see [this post](http://www.jessesquires.com/migrating-to-swift-3/) for details on a popular approach). I checked SwiftyJSON and it appears to have a branch for Swift 3, so you could convert your app to Swift 3 and give that a try. In order to use it, change the SwiftyJSON entry in your Podfile to:

```rb
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```

It's up to the project to update for each Xcode 8 beta, so it may not be exactly working, but it is likely that there will be fewer than 100 errors.

**Note**: You may see a “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” error after updating everything and fixing the complier errors. This can be fixed by adding a `post_install` step to your Podfile (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5521#issuecomment-226328062)), or by updating to CocoaPods 1.1.0.beta.1 or higher (`gem install cocoapods --pre`).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience when starting up the workspace, the SDK should ask you if you'd like to convert your code to Swift 3 or do it "later".  By just selecting later, it won't migrate your code to swift 3.  I must warn you though that I went through the same thing and it was almost impossible to work backwards just because you want to use the latest and greatest Xcode 8.  You'll eventually run into problems such as when you're ready to push to the app store and iTunesConnect won't accept any files that are lower than version 10.  Also when and if another developer inherits your code, they will have problems if they are using an earlier version of Xcode.

Comment: i tapped the migration button impatiently and found that it is difficult if not impossible to de-migrate, given you haven't committed in a conveniently recent time..

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the end of your `Podfile` then run `pod install`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
    end
  end
end
```